# Optimizing code to bind event listeners to dynamic elements rendered via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The question here is about the right (best-practice) way to bind event listeners to elements that are *dynamic*.

For example, consider the code below. We have two buttons with class `show_alert`. The first one is static, and the second dynamic in a sense that it appears only after the user performs some action (in this case, presses a button with class `render-button`).

Now the question:

Previously, I used the following code to bind events to such dynamic elements:

```
$('document').on('click', '.show-alert', function(e){
    alert('Hello');
});
```

But the problem with this code is that the DOM-tree is rebuilt everytime which is bad.

So I improved it the following way:

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.show-alert', function(e){
    alert('Hello');
});
```

where `.parent` is a DOM-element which I am sure is static. 
The logic is: choose a wrapper that is static and bind all elements to it:

```
$('.static_wrapper').on('click', '.target-class', function(e){
    alert('Hello');
});
```

THE QUESTION:

Is this logic of choosing a static wrapper a significant improvement to 
`$('document').on('click', '.target-class', function(e){...`. Doesn't the issue of DOM-tree rebuilding still persist if you have an interface where a considerable part is dynamic and you have to choose a static element which is very high in a DOM-tree? Like

```
<div class="static-wrapper">
    <div>
        <div>
            <!-- and still many many divs...... -->
                     <div class="target-class"
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     var str = '<div class="second-parent">' +
               '<button class="show-alert">Dynamic button</button>' +
              '</div>'
     $('.render-button').on('click', function(e){
        $('.parent').append(str);
     });
     
     /*
     $('.show-alert').on('click', function(e){
         alert('Hello');
     });
     */
     $('.parent').on('click', '.show-alert', function(e){
         alert('Hello');
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = 'parent'>
      <div class="second-parent">
          <button class="render-button">Press to render dynamic button</button>
      </div>
      <div class="second-parent">
          <button class="show-alert">Static button</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that delegating event listeners causes dom rebuild?

Comment: Well, maybe I am explaining incorrectly, but they told me that `$(document).on('click', '.target-class', function(e)` is very bad code.

Comment: *"very bad"* is far too extreme. It is a minor optimization moving it down from document